# Tkinter: Update widget from different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a Tkinter application that I'm writing in Python 3.
I've got one module which contains a class in which I create all my widgets. I'm trying to update a progress bar from a separate module that does the heavy lifting.

```
#GUI.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import Work_Module

progress_bar = None

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        master.title('CCD Creator  Version 1.0')
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=500)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        global progress_bar

        progress_bar = tk.ttk.Progressbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
        progress_bar.pack(side="bottom")

        self.run = tk.Button(self, text="  Run  ", fg="green", command=self.do_work)
        self.run.pack(side="top")

        #Continue creating various widgets that don't need to be updated by other modules

    def do_work(self):
        Work_Module.main()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Here is the module with a class that does the "heavy lifting" that I want to track the progress on.

```
#Work_Module.py

class Work:
    def __init__(self):
    #Do some intensive work


main():
    for idx, job in enumerate(work_list):
        Work()
        import GUI
        percentage_done = idx / len(job_list) * 100
        GUI.progress_bar.step(percentage_done)
```

The problem I'm running into is that progress_bar has a value of None in the Work_Module. It's assigned an object in the GUI module, but that object isn't retained when trying to reference it from the Work_Module. I know that importing GUI in the main method is kind of strange, and I suspect that this is some sort of namespace issue or circular import problem, but I can't seem to think of a way to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to inject the `progress_bar` into `Work_Module` just before you call the `mainloop()`:

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    Work_Module.progress_bar = progress_bar
    app.mainloop()
```

If you like, you can also dispense with the `global` aspect of the `progress_bar`:

```
    def create_widgets(self):
        # global progress_bar (no longer needed)
        # add 'self'
        self.progress_bar = tk.ttk.Progressbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
        self.progress_bar.pack(side="bottom")
        ...

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    Work_Module.progress_bar = self.progress_bar  # add 'self'
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solved the problem of None type being assigned to progress_bar, but now the issue I'm seeing is that the progress bar doesn't incrementally update. After the work_module finishes all it's work, the progress bar just jumps to the end.

Comment: @sager89: you probably have to let/tell `tkinter` update the screen.

Comment: I had to create a separate thread to do the work, since the GUI is a blocking call. After that, it worked!